# Import folders in Eclipse with ctrl-click references available

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a folder with several subfolders within it, and I want to import them in Eclipse.

I am not sure what is the right way to do that. Indeed, although I can import the folder, I am not able to obtain the ctrl-click feature on the imported folders to navigate between references and declarations.

I am using Eclipse Luna and it is a Java project.

Comment: Welcome to the site, please take a minute and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Luna in a while, but did you try importing all the folders, building and then refactoring the project? This should allow Eclipse to nativize the references and enable ctrl-click navigation.